# Problema ao remover o primeiro nó da lista duplamente encadeada

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Boa noite,

Estou tentando resolver uma questão que pedia para remover os alunos cujo CR é menor que 5. O meu maior problema é remover o primeiro nó (primeiro aluno) de uma lista duplamente encadeada quando se tem apenas um nó. Apenas dei free sobre o nó que contém o CR com valor menor que 5, e fiz a cabeça da lista apontar para NULL, que seria o endereço do nó sucessor ao que será excluído, nada demais. O resultado é que na hora de imprimir a lista, o nó continuou intacto, porém com valores aleatórios após a chamada do free(). Segue o print e o código fonte para melhor análise.

Conto com ajuda de todos!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    long matricula;
    char nome[51];
    float CR;

}DADOS_ALUNO;


typedef struct {

    DADOS_ALUNO dados; //Dados do aluno
    void* pProximoAluno; //Ponteiro para o próximo aluno
    void* pAlunoAnterior; //Ponteiro para aluno anterior

}ELEMENTO;


ELEMENTO* criaLista(){
    return NULL;
}


ELEMENTO* cadastraAlunos(ELEMENTO* lista, DADOS_ALUNO novo_aluno){

    ELEMENTO* novo = (ELEMENTO*)malloc(sizeof(ELEMENTO));

    //Inicialmente os ponteiros ini e fim apontam para NULL
    ELEMENTO* ini = lista;
    ELEMENTO* fim = lista;

    if(novo == NULL){
        printf("Memoria insuficiente\n");
        exit(1);

    } else if(lista == NULL){ //Se a lista estiver vazia, insere o primeiro nó

        novo->dados = novo_aluno;
        novo->pProximoAluno = fim;
        novo->pAlunoAnterior = ini;

        fim = ini = novo;

        return ini;

    } else { //Caso a lista tenha pelo menos um nó

        novo->dados = novo_aluno;
        novo->pProximoAluno = fim;
        novo->pAlunoAnterior = NULL;
        fim->pAlunoAnterior = novo;
        ini = novo;

        return ini;

    }

}

//a)Retornar a quantidade de alunos com coeficiente de rendimento maior ou igual a 7.
int numAlunosCrAlto(ELEMENTO* pLista){

    int quantidade = 0;

    ELEMENTO* p = pLista; //Ponteiro que aponta para o início da lista para percorrê-lo


    if(pLista == NULL){
        printf("Lista vazia\n");
        exit(1);

    } else {

        while(p != NULL){

            if(p->dados.CR >= 7){
                quantidade++;
            }

            p = p->pProximoAluno;
        }

        return quantidade;  
    }   
}

void imprimeAluno(ELEMENTO* lista){

    ELEMENTO* p = lista;

    if(lista == NULL){
        printf("Lista vazia\n");
        exit(1);

    } else {

    for(; p != NULL; p = p->pProximoAluno){
        printf("Matricula: %ld - Nome: %s - CR: %.2f\n", p->dados.matricula, p->dados.nome, p->dados.CR);
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    }
}


//b)Excluir da lista todos os alunos com coeficiente de rendimento menor que 5.
void excluirAlunosCrBaixo(ELEMENTO* pLista){

    ELEMENTO* p = pLista; //Ponteiro que aponta para o primeiro nó da lista para percorrê-la
    ELEMENTO* ant = NULL; //Ponteiro para guardar o nó antecessor ao que será excluído

    if(pLista == NULL){
        printf("Lista vazia\n");
        exit(1);

    } else {

        while(p != NULL){

            if(p->dados.CR < 5 && p->pAlunoAnterior == NULL){ //Se for primeiro da lista

            if(p->pProximoAluno == NULL){ //Se não houver mais elementos na lista, a mesma fica vazia

                ant = p; /*Usando o ponteiro ant para apontar ao p e chamar o free() sobre ele para 
                         não perder a referência de p, pois este será utilizado para percorrer a lista*/

                pLista = ant->pProximoAluno; //A cabeça da lista aponta para NULL, indicando que está vazia
                free(ant); 

            } else { //Caso ainda exista mais elementos na lista, o segundo elemento passa a ser o primeiro

                ant = p;
                p = p->pProximoAluno;
                free(ant);
                p->pAlunoAnterior = NULL;
            }


            } else if(p->dados.CR < 5 && p->pAlunoAnterior != NULL && p->pProximoAluno != NULL){ //Se o elemento estiver no meio da lista

                ELEMENTO* aux; //Ponteiro que irá apontar para o nó antecessor ao nó que será excluído
                ant = p;
                aux = ant->pAlunoAnterior;  
                p = p->pProximoAluno;
                p->pAlunoAnterior = aux;
                aux->pProximoAluno = p;
                free(ant);

            } else if(p->dados.CR < 5 && p->pProximoAluno == NULL){ //Se for o último da lista


                ant = p->pAlunoAnterior;
                ant->pProximoAluno = NULL;
                free(p);

            }

            p = p->pProximoAluno;       
        }
    }   
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    ELEMENTO* Lista = (ELEMENTO*)malloc(sizeof(ELEMENTO));

    if(Lista == NULL){
        printf("Memoria insuficiente\n");
        exit(1);

    } else {

        Lista = criaLista();

//      DADOS_ALUNO a1 = {201311, "Teste 01", 8.5};
//      DADOS_ALUNO a2 = {201412, "Teste 02", 6.3};
//      DADOS_ALUNO a3 = {201211, "Teste 03", 6.2};
        DADOS_ALUNO a4 = {201511, "Teste 04", 1.0};

//      Lista = cadastraAlunos(Lista, a1);
//      Lista = cadastraAlunos(Lista, a2);
//      Lista = cadastraAlunos(Lista, a3);
        Lista = cadastraAlunos(Lista, a4);

        imprimeAluno(Lista);

        excluirAlunosCrBaixo(Lista);

        imprimeAluno(Lista);

        printf("Total de alunos com CR maior ou igual a 7: %d", numAlunosCrAlto(Lista));

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na linha 132 faça uma chamada da sua função de imprimir a lista, você verá que o seu código está realmente excluindo, no entanto, não esta atualizando o ponteiro para *NULL* (isso é muito recorrente em implementações de listas em *C*).

O que acontece é que apesar de você estar mandando seus parâmetros por endereço de memória, em *C*, você não consegue alterar o endereço de memória dentro do escopo da função (em outros termos, seria como se o endereço da variável fosse passado por valor). Para ilustrar melhor segue um exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void change(int *v ,int *b){
    v=b;
    printf("Dentro da fução\n");
    printf("%d\n", *v);
}

int main(){
    int *v1;

    int a=10;
    int b=5;
    *v1=a;

    change(v1,&b);
    printf("Fora da função\n");
    printf("%d\n", *v1);
 return 0;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Possíveis soluções que você poderia estar implementando são listas com **cabeçalhos** (estruturas que guardam a posição do inicio da sua lista e o final), assim você poderia enviar ponteiros de ponteiros para suas funções resolvendo o problema ou alterar as suas funções para o tipo de retorno **ELEMENTO***

Comment: Já resolvi o problema. Realmente seria melhor declarar mais um struct contendo um ponteiro que armazena o primeiro e o último, e deu certo. No exercício pedia pra que as funções sejam void mesmo. De qualquer forma, obrigado pela sugestão.